# Color behind activity

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

Im playing with some in between activities transition animation. When one activity is scaled and moved into center you can see black background behind it. My question is: how to change this background color?

I've tried all options on window object - both from code and styles.xml. Note, setting windowIsTransculent=true is not the effect I want to achieve.

Thanks for answer!

Comment: not possible remove the black color between activity transition.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible remove the black color between activity transition in some cases such as some 3D style animations or delay between activity  A n B transition .  Only way is to hide black color. Give a proper animation that covers your complete screen with activity A or B (like slide, alpha) or finish A after complete launch of B

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 basic themes that all other themes are extended from (last time I checked).

These have white background, black background or translucent background.

As a test, make both activities (from and to) use the theme `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` and see if this helps.

I would assume that you're current using a theme which extends from the black background base theme.

Comment: Unluckilly, none of the themes helped me to achieve my goal. Thanks for your input anyway!